# how to make selected row after crud in jqgrid and php

Tags: javascript, php, jqgrid

how do I use jqgrid and php so that I can use the selected row after crud feature meaning that when the added data form is submitted, the program can highlight which row according to its position so that users can recognize changes that occur after inputting data I've tried using ajax but can't

how do I use jqgrid and php for example like the web https://web.transporindo.com/mdgrid/ so that I can use the selected row after crud feature meaning that when the added data form is submitted, the program can highlight which row according to its position so that users can recognize changes that occur after inputting data I've tried using ajax but can't. I've tried using ajax by calling the function callAfterSubmit(response, postData, pass) and sending it to add_header.php which contains

JQGRID

```js
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('navGrid', '#jqGridPager', null, {

  recreateForm: true,                       //formulir akan dibuat ulang setiap kali dialog diaktifkan dengan opsi baru dari colModel
  beforeShowForm: function(form) {
    form[0].querySelector('#no_invoice').setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly')
    // var input     = document.getElementById("no_invoice").value;
    // var inputBaru = input.replace('<span class="highlight"></span>', ""); // Menghapus kataHapus dari input menggunakan replace()
    // document.getElementById("no_invoice").value = inputBaru;
    var nilaiAsli     = "";
    var no_invoice    = document.getElementById("no_invoice");      // Ambil element input no_invoice
    var tgl_pembelian  = document.getElementById("tgl_pembelian");  // Ambil element input tgl_pembelian
    var nama_pelanggan = document.getElementById("nama_pelanggan"); // Ambil element input nama_pelanggan
    var jenis_kelamin  = document.getElementById("jenis_kelamin");  // Ambil element input jenis_kelamin
    var saldo          = document.getElementById("saldo");          // Ambil element input saldo

    nilaiAsli        = no_invoice.value;                         // Simpan nilai asli dari input pada variabel nilaiAsli
    var inputBaru    = no_invoice.value.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, ""); // Menghapus elemen tag HTML dari input menggunakan regex
    no_invoice.value = inputBaru;                                // Tampilkan input yang telah diubah

    nilaiAsli           = tgl_pembelian.value;                         // Simpan nilai asli dari input pada variabel nilaiAsli
    var inputBaru       = tgl_pembelian.value.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, ""); // Menghapus elemen tag HTML dari input menggunakan regex
    tgl_pembelian.value = inputBaru;                                   // Tampilkan input yang telah diubah

    nilaiAsli            = nama_pelanggan.value;                         // Simpan nilai asli dari input pada variabel nilaiAsli
    var inputBaru        = nama_pelanggan.value.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, ""); // Menghapus elemen tag HTML dari input menggunakan regex
    nama_pelanggan.value = inputBaru;                                    // Tampilkan input yang telah diubah

    nilaiAsli           = jenis_kelamin.value;                         // Simpan nilai asli dari input pada variabel nilaiAsli
    var inputBaru       = jenis_kelamin.value.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, ""); // Menghapus elemen tag HTML dari input menggunakan regex
    jenis_kelamin.value = inputBaru;                                   // Tampilkan input yang telah diubah

    nilaiAsli     = saldo.value;                         // Simpan nilai asli dari input pada variabel nilaiAsli
    var inputBaru = saldo.value.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, ""); // Menghapus elemen tag HTML dari input menggunakan regex
    saldo.value   = inputBaru;                           // Tampilkan input yang telah diubah
  },
  // afterSubmit:callAfterSubmit,
  // reloadAfterSubmit:true,

}, {
  afterSubmit: callAfterSubmit,
  recreateForm: true,
}, );

function callAfterSubmit(response, postData, oper) {
  let sortfield   = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData').sidx;
  let sortorder   = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData').sord;
  let pagesize    = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData').rows;
  let selectedRow = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');

  $.ajax({
      url      : "add_header.php",
      dataType : 'JSON',
      data: {
        no_invoice  : JSON.parse(response.responseText).no_invoice,
        sidx        : sortfield,
        sord        : sortorder,
        selectedRow : selectedRow
      }
    })
  .done(function(data) {
    $('#cData').click();
    let posisi = data.position;
    let pager  = Math.ceil(posisi / pagesize);
    let rows   = posisi - (pager - 1) * pagesize;
    indexRow   = rows - 1;
    $('#grid_id').trigger('reloadGrid', { page: pager });

    // Setelah berhasil mengupdate data, kita dapat memilih kembali baris yang dipilih sebelumnya
    $('#grid_id').jqGrid('setSelection', selectedRow);
  });
}
```

PHP add_header.php

```
<?php
require "db.php";

if(isset($_GET['no_invoice']) && isset($_GET['sidx']) && isset($_GET['sord'])) {
    $no_invoice = $_GET['no_invoice'];
    $sortfield  = $_GET['sidx']; 
    $sortorder  = $_GET['sord'];
    
    $position = getWithPosition($no_invoice, $sortfield, $sortorder, $koneksi);
    
    function getWithPosition($no_invoice, $sortfield, $sortorder, $koneksi) {
        $data = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT temp.position, temp.*
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position, penjualan.*
            FROM penjualan
            JOIN 
            (
                SELECT @rownum := 0
            ) rownum ORDER BY penjualan.$sortfield $sortorder
        ) temp WHERE temp.no_invoice = '". $no_invoice ."'");

        if(!$data) {
            die("Query failed: " . mysqli_error($koneksi));
        }

        $post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
        $pos = $post['position'];
        return $pos;
    }
    
    $response = ['no_invoice' => $no_invoice, 'position' => $position];
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else {
    echo "Error: Missing parameters";
}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see which questions are on-topic on this site.

Answer (score 0):

For me it is difficult to understand what you want do, but after submitting the form the record stay selected. It is highly recommended to check the options in form editing.

Demo can [be seen here](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/edit_add_delete/dialogs/index.html)

[Documentation is here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/editing/#edit-grid-row)